# How could set minibuffer taking visual-line-mode as default?

Tags: emacs

I set `global-visual-line-mode` but it does not affect the minibuffer.

Tried to add `visual-line-mode` to `minibuffer-hook`, but fails to find such a hook named `minibuffer-hook`.

How could set minibuffer taking "visual-line-mode" as default?

Comment: Not sure this is a good idea, but the name of the hook you want is `minibuffer-setup-hook`. If you do `C-h v minibuffer--hook TAB` you get completion on all the variables that match.

Comment: thank you sir @NickD